# Interaction with a non-Web Application with an API (Virtual Trader Specifically)

Tags: java, python, oracle, ui-automation, build-automation

**TL;DR When an API is not available what resources does a programmer have to manipulate an application programmatically?**

The company I work for uses an application called [Virtual Trader](https://www.virtualtrader.com/about) to help automate inter-company transactions. I'm still learning a lot about it, but best I understand it so far its a 3rd party application that is installed on top of the Oracle database.

Essentially, my question is when an API is not available what resources does a programmer have to manipulate an application programmatically?

Essentially, the GUI is extremely tedious for logging journal entries. So much so , that we assemble all the formulas we need in an excel document and painfully copy and paste them as we put the automation into "production".

So from a high level, how could I go about getting started just trying to manipulate VT without an API? Is there a general approach to this kind of problem?

Comment: if it use network connection then you can try to catch this connection, analyze it and create code which works the same - but it is hard work (`reverse engineering`). If you have GUI then you can use modules like [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to control mouse/keyboard and automatically click elements in GUI.

Comment: You may ask to development team for the DB queries they use with API so that will help you run them with your excel. Even a small application would work out for you to read excel, send over query, and get the results.

Answer (score 0):

The GUI (Oracle forms) does have it's limitations regardless of the ISV. Virtual Trader does have MJ Import to take spreadsheets or speak to them about providing REST API. Oracle ORDS has opened up a lot of opportunities for REST API's to be quickly developed and is free with the Database license. An alternative is to use a 3rd party like More4Apps to take Excel directly into the MJ Interface and kick off the import.